# How to handle XSS on href

Tags: javascript, xss

I have html page which has a script

```
Test.html
<html>
<body>
 <script>
  alert(document.cookie);
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

href link

```
<a href=Test.html target="_blank">Test</a>
```

On click of Test link it open new tab and execute the javascript.This script has vulnerability. 
I want to disable the all javascript for new tab or any alternate solution to handle such XSS vulnerability.

Comment: It's a known problem, to say the least, (which you seem to know since you know it's called XSS). Do some research.

Comment: All solution i found which are talking about internal HTML page.But this page is injected by external entity

Comment: "This script has vulnerability." No it doesn't. What vulnerability? Where? If you think there's something wrong with that code, then don't write that code.

Comment: This is a sample script and script is injected by external entity.User may add any hacking script and can hack our software information.So i want to block execution of such harming script\

Comment: @MayurB Then don't let users do that.

Comment: @Boann It comes as an attachment in email...We don't have control on that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used iFrame tag to load HTML i.e  `<iframe src="Test.html" sandbox></iframe>` .Iframe has [Sandbox](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_iframe_sandbox.asp) attribute which block all execution of javascripts. For IE 9 and Below iframe has [Security](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms534622%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) attribute which do the same job.